# How To Install D-Link DWM-156 3G Modem Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: drivers, usb-modem, 3g

I bought a new D-Link 3G modem and it said it supports Linux. But after I installed it, I still can’t make the device work on Ubuntu 13.04.

I used the .deb file from the D-link modem `3g_modem_connect_D300_i386.deb` (from the modem itself) but I was unable to configure it. I searched the Internet, they use `dlinkusbmodem.deb` file, which is a file from 1 year ago. Even after I dpkg it, I still don’t know how to proceed.
I viewed [this youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4NU8F3g1_Dc)  and it doesn't work with this file version.

Comment: You should try [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Type <kbd>ctrl+alt+t</kbd>
Then a terminal will appear.

Type

```
sudo mkdir /media/dlink
```

Then type

```
sudo mount /dev/sr1 or /dev/sr2 /media/dlink
```

There you will see a file called **dlinkusbmodem.deb**

After installing the package the thing you have to do is to type

```
usbdeviceswitchdlink
```

After doing that you will notice that the modem in unmounted.

Now type

```
3g_connect.sh ttyUSB0
```

Then wait for 120 seconds.

You'll see that before or after 120 seconds the internet is connected.

To check type

```
ping www.google.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I could find is to connect the modem and then eject it, then setting it up. Steps:

1. Connect your modem. DO NOT INSTALL ANYTHING.
2. Click on the eject icon in nautilus. DO NOT DISCONNECT YOUR MODEM.
3. Wait for some minutes and then go to networks options (should vary according to DE).
4. Set it up by selecting your country, service provider and access points. Click "Done" or "Finish".

You're good to go!

Answer (score -1):

put the .deb file on Downloads
and do this on terminal:

```
sudo -s
cd Downloads
sudo dpkg -i 3g_modem_connect_D300_i386.deb
```

I think thats the only way. Hope it works.

Comment: Why the first `sudo -s`?

Comment: No it does not works. I installed it. Its says installation finished, but I couldn't find the dlink file in my system.

Answer (score -1):

This answer applies to Linux Mint Cinnamon 20.3, and it may apply to newer versions of Ubuntu as well:

I have the same modem and it works without any installation. You just need to create an access point using "mobile broadband" option in Linux and the access point values and instructions must be available in  your mobile operator's website.

In addition, my modem came with a CD that had .deb files with drivers for the modem. For me it worked without having to install the drivers.

Comment: I assume you aren't using Ubuntu 13.04 (what the original question is for). Perhaps [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1412908/edit) your answer to make it clear which version of Ubuntu this is valid for.

Comment: I use mint cinnamon latest version and one thing I forgot to say is that you can find 2 files of Deb format in modem cd drive. one of 32bits and the other of64 amd that installs the modem but I didn't have to install it and the modem worked well after creating the mobile broadband access point.

Comment: LM is not Ubuntu. It is off topic here.