# how do I Install my USB router software

Tags: 16.04, usb, usb-modem

I have a D-Link router at home and wish to use it with my Ubuntu installation which is a 16.04 LTS version. However the slight problem is that the router cannot be detected by my Ubuntu installation.

However on analyzing the files in the the USB router's drive I found a .deb file which I presume is an installation file for the software of the router. So how do I install my router's software on Ubuntu when it does not even detect the USB Router which contains the deb file

Comment: What is the name and manufacturer of your Router?

Comment: The manufacturer is D-Link and device name is DWM 156

Comment: Possible?  https://askubuntu.com/questions/347637/how-to-install-d-link-dwm-156-3g-modem-ubuntu-13-04  And a step was missed.  To install a .deb file, it is `sudo dpkg -i nameoffile.deb`

Comment: @Terrance. I tried what was suggested but the second step errors saying     mount: can't find /dev/sr1/media/dlink in /etc/fstab. What should I do ?

Comment: When you plug that modem in it shows up as a `/dev/sr?` device.  Get a `ls /dev/sr?` before you plug in the modem, then do it again after you plug it in, and you should see a new name there, according to those instructions.  I don't own one of these so I do not know much further than that.  The link I posted was only a suggestion to try.

Comment: Now it says /dev/sr(1/2) does not exist whenever I try to mount it. also there is no sr(1/2) folder or file in the dev directory in root

Comment: Don't worry about that then.  Did you install the .deb file that you downloaded from their site?  If you did, then all you should have to do when your router is connected to your host is run the command `3g_connect.sh ttyUSB0` and wait the 120 seconds like it was suggested.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54073/discussion-between-suhrid-mulay-and-terrance).